# Show result of an operation (multiplication) in textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I have a textblock, a button and a textbox.
What I want is the user enter data in a textbox (only numbers - whole numbers or decimals) and press the button appears on the textblock the result of an operation (multiplication) based on the value that the user entered.

For exemple (Button Click Event)
int num = TextBox.Text;
TextBlock.Text = num * 0.02;

What I want is: the user enters in the TextBox a decimal or integer (eg 50), when you press the button want to appear in the TextBlock the value that the user entered * 0.02. The result to appear is 1

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to parse the string
you can use the `int num = Int.Parse(TextBox.Text)` method

Just don't forget to validate the TextBox so it contains only numbers

Answer (score 0):

C# is a type safe language, so you can't calculate "hello" (string) * 1 (int).
So you have to parse the string into the correct type. Because you not only need whole numbers, you have to choose between decimal and double.

Also the user can enter an invalid number, so better to check the Input.

This will look like:

```
  const decimal multiplicator = 0.02;
  double number;
  if (Double.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out number))
  {
    var result = number * multiplicator;
    //do what you want with the result ;)
  }else
  {
    //TextBox.Text is not a valid number!
  }
```